# Elegantly modifying an existing link's parameters with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex, parameters

I want to use javascript to find part of this link with lots of parameters:

```
<a class="" data-method="post" href="/daily_drills?commonality%5B%5D=category&amp;commonality%5B%5D=2&amp;daily_drill%5Bgroup_id%5D=2&amp;drill_ids%5B%5D=7&amp;drill_ids%5B%5D=4&amp;drill_ids%5B%5D=3&amp;group=2" id="done-button" rel="nofollow">Done</a>
```

And add / remove numbers to / from the parameter drill_ids

In the above example, the `drill_ids` param contains `["7", "4", "3"]`:

```
drill_ids%5B%5D=7&amp;drill_ids%5B%5D=4&amp;drill_ids%5B%5D=3
```

I have a method that fires when a user clicks a number on the page, if they click "7" I want to remove "7" from the drill_ids params.  If they click a number that's not present in the params, I want to append it to the drill_ids params.

- Since I could render this link as a partial I was thinking of re-rendering the entire thing with the appended drill_ids param, but that would not have an instantaneous response time on a weaker connection.
- I -could- just go in regex style and add/remove drill_ids%5B%5D=7& (for the number 7), but it seems like there'd be a cleaner way of doing this.

Any tips for how I should approach this?

Comment: instead of reading/parsing the link, just rebuild it from scratch each time. you'd spend less cpu/code time doing that than having to build a small parser for tearing apart the link.

Comment: You would have to parse each, You could use a split function to get each individual drill_ids and check the value there, but I would probably rebuild it as Marc B suggested

Comment: Store the parameters in an object on the anchor element's data object, then regenerate the param string using $.param whenever you change one of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a simple javascript match as I could not come up with a clever clean solution:

```
// I build up a string that I want to replace the old string with

// create a list of the ids that I wanted to append
listOfIds = ""
arrayOfIds.forEach (id) ->
  listOfIds = listOfIds+id

// grab the old link in it's entirety
oldLink = $("#done-button").attr("href")
console.log(oldLink)

// grab the string from the old link I don't want
match = oldLink.match(/(?:group_id%5D=2)(.*)(?=&group=)/)[1]

// replace the old string with the new string
newLink = oldLink.replace(match, listOfIds)

// changed the href attribute on the link
$("#done-button").attr('href', newLink)
```